# Work Item view rights

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to hide specific TFS work item types for some user groups? E.g. Client should not see **Bugs**.

Is there a way to hide specific WI fields. E.g. Client should not see **Estimation** field.

The only way that I know so far is using the security rights on the WI area field.
That allows you to create specific areas, remove read rights for some users/groups and than all WI in that area will not be visible. The problem is this ads new responsibility to the area field that leads to duplicate tree structure.

I am aiming for more flexibility, maybe something at field level. 
I really can't understand how this is still not available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe there is a way for creating new Work Item Templates tailored for customer's view!

Comment: Do your clients need direct access to the TFS server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is level of security granularity is not available these days.

What you can do is make an integration with another system like sharepoint where you expose the fields you want. You can use the [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) for this .